# Backup & Restore Winsock?

Tags: backup, restore, netsh

In the process of doing some troubleshooting and running the `netsh winsock reset` command, and was wondering if anyone is aware of a way (or app) to backup the current winsock catalog (and/or everything the `reset` command resets/removes) also with an option to restore those values if wanted?

Google-Fu has turned up nothing for me so far.

Comment: @FrankThomas what's the Long answer? I'm one of those people who hates being told I can't do something, lol. Maybe a registry key backup/restore, or some other sort of hacky workaround?

Comment: What exactly are you worried about losing and want to recover?  There is nothing in the "catalog" that needs to be saved AFAIK.  If this is a personal exercise, then I would suggest using the process monitor against netsh to find your answer.  It should be clear what it is clearing out when this command is run.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas It's a bit of both; personal exercise and also actually wanting to back it up, with the potential to restore if ever wanting to. I would assume since it's a 'catalog' that stores some sort of config, and resetting it clears this config, then there may be a chance I'd want to back up that config? If I watch a process monitor I'd have to reset it all w/out backup first, in order to watch it, no?

Comment: I would *guess* that if you run the command.. you will see what keys are hit regardless of the amount of data being stored.  Also, TCP socket code only has a few variables and I can't imagine what on earth would need to be cached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@John helped me answer this question by answering [MY question](https://superuser.com/questions/1771392/what-is-stored-in-the-winsock-catalog).  THANKS JOHN!

I believe that you can back up (and restore) the keys under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\WinSock2\Parameters` but I have not verified the restore.  Do this at your own risk (which I believe to be very small).

If you examine these keys, you will find that it already makes a backup for you!  Your current settings appear to be under a key called `NameSpace_CatalogX` where X is some number and the backup from the last time it was reset is stored under `Protocol_Catalog_Before_Reset`.

### What changed in there?

1. Open a Command Prompt as an administrator.
2. Copy and run the following command to save the results of the Winsock catalog to a file prior to resetting the Winsock catalog. `netsh winsock show catalog > c:\somepath\winsock-before.txt`
3. Now that we have a backup, reset your catalog. `netsh winsock reset`
4. Take another snapshot to see the differences. `netsh winsock show catalog > c:\somepath\winsock-after.txt`

TO BE CLEAR:

1. I am GUESSING (and I am probably correct) but still guessing.
2. This information is *probably* pointless to store as it will rebuild itself as needed.
3. All of this was learned by sleuthing my own machine after @John provided me with [this link](https://adamtheautomator.com/netsh-winsock-reset/#:%7E:text=Besides%20acting%20as%20an%20API,%2C%20such%20as%20TCP%2FIP)

Comment: Good info! My take on it is, that its pointless to restore the catalog, in much the same way you can't restore the TCP port state for a system after a reboot. an application asked to open that port, and establishing the port without the application is not meaningful. instead you run the application and let it create its ports. NSP/LSPs are similar in that they are a mapping associated with the service/application, and not something that can meaningfully exist on their own.

Comment: Perfect answer, TY!

Comment: @FrankThomas For the sake of discussion (not argument, because I see your point), the reset function itself makes a backup; there must be some reason. Backups exist for 1 reason; restoration (if needed).

Comment: This functionality might date back to the "good ol days" when gathering the data on your P133 and a modem were expensive.