# What is stored in the "Winsock Catalog"?

Tags: windows, tcp, winsock

[Another user's question](https://superuser.com/questions/1771273/backup-restore-winsock?noredirect=1#comment2759373_1771273) prompted me to write this one.

***I have no purpose for the question other than curiosity.***

Does anyone actually KNOW what is stored in what is called the [Winsock Catalog](https://www.howtogeek.com/785351/how-and-why-to-perform-a-netsh-winsock-reset-on-windows/)?  At the moment, I can't think of any reason to cache socket information but I am sure there must be a purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably what you are looking for:

[Winsock Catalog](https://adamtheautomator.com/netsh-winsock-reset/#:%7E:text=Besides%20acting%20as%20an%20API,%2C%20such%20as%20TCP%2FIP)

Besides acting as an API, Winsock stores its settings in a database known as the Winsock catalog. In Windows 10 the catalog stores both namespace providers, providing a map between Winsock and a service such as DNS, and base service providers which provides detail on network protocols, such as TCP/IP.

Resetting Winsock is best done through the Windows command-line tool netsh. The netsh command displays and modifies the running computer’s network configuration, along with resetting the Winsock catalog.

To view the current catalog entries, try running the command `netsh winsock show catalog`